# Openymsg for android

Tags: java, android, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-messenger

I am developing YM client for Android. I've included the openymsg0.5 api. When I run the program it shows following error.

```
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206): org.openymsg.network.LoginRefusedException: Login Failed, unable to retrieve stage 2 url
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206):     at org.openymsg.network.Session.yahooAuth16Stage2(Session.java:2048)
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206):     at org.openymsg.network.Session.yahooAuth16Stage1(Session.java:1955)
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206):     at org.openymsg.network.Session.receiveAuth(Session.java:1848)
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206):     at org.openymsg.network.InputThread.processPayload(InputThread.java:139)
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206):     at org.openymsg.network.InputThread.process(InputThread.java:129)
06-29 11:32:04.097: ERROR/InputThread(11206):     at org.openymsg.network.InputThread.run(InputThread.java:71)
```

This is the main error:

`LoginRefusedException: Login Failed, unable to retrieve stage 2 url`

This question has been asked before but I haven't found an answer that has helped me. Does anyone have any idea about how to deal with this error? I have gone through the openymsg test code and code base and everything seems to be fine.

I just checked , it works fine as a java application but if used as part of android it gives log in error .I am creating session as follows

```
Session session = new Session();
session.addSessionListener(new SessionListenerClass());
try{
    session.login("username", "password");
    if (session!=null 
        && session.getSessionStatus()== SessionState.LOGGED_ON) 
    {
        System.out.println("It logged on!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

SessionListner :

```
public class SessionListenerClass extends SessionAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(SessionEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.messageReceived(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyReceived(SessionNotifyEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.notifyReceived(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void newMailReceived(SessionNewMailEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.newMailReceived(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void errorPacketReceived(SessionErrorEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.errorPacketReceived(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed(SessionEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.connectionClosed(event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you're sure your Device/Emulator has a working Internet-connection? Did you declare the Internet-privilege in the Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes the device can use 3G and i have added <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Is there anything specific to android ???which i am missing out here , cause when i test with my laptop just as normal java program the above code returns sessionStatus as logged in , but with android throws an error

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using is based on the [jYMSG](http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/)-library, which has a way better documentation.

The Documentation for your thrown exception, the [LoginRefusedException](http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/docs/ymsg/network/LoginRefusedException.html) reads:

> Returns the status code given by the
>   server. This will one of the values
>   specified in StatusConstants. Values
>   will be either STATUS_BADUSERNAME for
>   an unknown account, or STATUS_BAD for
>   a bad password (or other fault).

So you can check if it's "something else" or just a wrong username/password.

---

Okay, this seams to be a bug in the library. I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openymsg/forums/forum/889139/topic/3876255) which shows that one of the project leaders knows about the problem. But I'm not sure if this will be fixed soon.

You should also notice, that the project is marked as "alpha". I can only suggest that you stay tuned for new releases which fix this issue.

Comment: As i told i tried the same code as java application and it works fine . I am debugging with source code of that library .I see that yahooAuth16Stage2 method throws exception , that is response code obtained from

Comment: String loginLink = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/pwtoken_login?src=ymsgr&ts=&token=" + token;
 URL u = new URL(loginLink);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();                                               uc.getResponseCode returns -1 instead of 200 wihich is HTTP_OK

Comment: Can you show the code from your `SessionListenerClass()`-class?

Comment: I have added that to part of my question , but we don get there to use this class , login only fails .It is specific to android .But stage one of connection passes which uses HttpUrlconnection and gets propery response code but second stage just return -1 , don see why is is happening , and what could be difference between pc and androidd phone

Comment: I updated my post. Have you tried using the original library (jYMSG) to archive this?

Comment: I got the problem , sorry for late update ..it was an issue due to two consecutive http calls. On adding the below line it works fine :          System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");